# Programming the BeagleBone to turn on LED, Got NodeJS errors

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, beagleboneblack

The assignment is about embedded system. We are learning how to use BeagleBone Black and how we can use it to make small-size devices e.g., devices that can measure temperature and pulse.

A part of our first assignment is to follow this guide: https://randomnerdtutorials.com/programming-the-beaglebone-black-with-bonescript/

We need to make a server in Node JS and a index in html. The site provides button to control a LED light that is connected to a breadboard via BeagleBone Black.

I have connected the LED, pins and wires to the BeagleBone Black. Installed Ubuntu 18.14, NodeJS, npm socket.io and Bonescript(Script dedicated to BeagleBone).

I am **not** using Cloud 9 IDE to run the server.js and index.html.
But I use terminal in Ubuntu.

To start the server i use this command: node server.js

I tried for several days to make the server and index.html to run,
but I get this error or nothing happends:

```
/home/ubuntu/bonescript/server.js:42
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
                              ^

[TypeError: require(...).listen is not a function
  at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/bonescript/server.js:42:31)
  at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
  at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
  at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
  at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
  at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Can anyone help me pinpoint the problem? I am really stuck on this stage. Thanks.

index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home Automation Web Server with BeagleBone</title>
    <script src = "/socket.io/socket.io.js" ></script>
    <script>
        // Establishing connection with server
        var socket = io.connect();

        // Changes the led state
        function changeState(state){
            if (state==1){
                // Emit message changing the state to 1
                socket.emit('changeState', '{"state":1}');
                // Change led status on web page to ON
                document.getElementById("outputStatus").innerHTML = "Status: ON";
            }
            else if (state==0){
                // Emit message changing the state to 0
                socket.emit('changeState', '{"state":0}');
                // Change led status on web page to OFF
                document.getElementById("outputStatus").innerHTML = "Status: OFF";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
    <h2>LED</h2>
    <p id="outputStatus">Status</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="changeState(1);">ON</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="changeState(0);">OFF</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

server.js code:

```
//Loading modules
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var b = require('bonescript');

// Create a variable called led, which refers to P9_14
var led = "P9_14";
// Initialize the led as an OUTPUT
b.pinMode(led, b.OUTPUT);

// Initialize the server on port 8888
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    // requesting files
    var file = '.'+((req.url=='/')?'/index.html':req.url);
    var fileExtension = path.extname(file);
    var contentType = 'text/html';
    // Uncoment if you want to add css to your web page
    /*
    if(fileExtension == '.css'){
        contentType = 'text/css';
    }*/
    fs.exists(file, function(exists){
        if(exists){
            fs.readFile(file, function(error, content){
                if(!error){
                    // Page found, write content
                    res.writeHead(200,{'content-type':contentType});
                    res.end(content);
                }
            })
        }
        else{
            // Page not found
            res.writeHead(404);
            res.end('Page not found');
        }
    })
}).listen(8888);

// Loading socket io module
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

// When communication is established
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('changeState', handleChangeState);
});

// Change led state when a button is pressed
function handleChangeState(data) {
    var newData = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log("LED = " + newData.state);
    // turns the LED ON or OFF
    b.digitalWrite(led, newData.state);
}

// Displaying a console message for user feedback
server.listen(console.log("Server Running ..."));
```

Comment: What version of bonescript are you running? What version of node do you have?

Comment: Current node version v16.13.0 and npm 8.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have same problem but solve it already the code on this website is based on older node version, you have to change the code on line

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

to

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

and edit variable or remove this line since newer node cant use .listen function twice (the code already use it on server var to open port 8888)

```
server.listen(console.log("Server Running ..."));
```

Comment: Thank you so much Settasak! I changed the both the lines of code. And it worked. You have no clue how much hour I spent to fix this. For ever greatfull!

Answer (score 1):

socket.io is an internal library, not an external one. Therefore, when you ran `npm install socket.io`, you downloaded something that is not the socket.io that you want.

Delete your node_modules, and remove socket.io from package.json, and reinstall bonescript via `npm install`. Then it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I will uninstall node modules and socket .io, and reinstall bonescript.

Comment: Did the suggestion work?

Comment: Takes some time to reinstall thing. I will notify you when everything is installed :)

Comment: Sadly It has not worked :(

Comment: What error message id you get?

Comment: Same: /var/lib/cloud9/Projects/server.js:30
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
                              ^

TypeError: require(...).listen is not a function

Comment: Installed Debian, and try to run on cloud9

Comment: Make sure you haven't installed socket.io globally. If its not globally installed, and not locally, then socket.io should worked. I was able to reproduce your problem, and fix it. So I'm sure what else it could be.

Comment: I will try again :) Is there a spesfic commands I need to type?

Comment: I just went back to the page, and it seems you are indeed installing it globally: sudo npm install -g socket.io. Try running sudo npm uninstall -g socket.io, and try again

Comment: Did not need to install socket.io as you said. Together with the example that Settasak wroted it worked. Thanks for the help :)